# Visualize scrlttr2 layout

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I made some layout changes to the `scrlttr2` class by changing some of the lengths that determine where the elements are put. Is there a way to generate something like this figure from the manual with the layout changes I made to get a better overview of the new layout?

I am mostly interested in the gray boxes, not so much in the arrows and labels.

[image: screen shot from the manual]

Comment: The original source file is [plength.dtx](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/source-doc/plength.dtx) (the `plenDIN` part), the processing is defined inside [Makefile.guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/source-doc/Makefile.guide), lines 286-292. Some of the needed variables are defined inside [Makefile.latexinit](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/source-doc/Makefile.latexinit).

Comment: With Letter Class Option `visualize.lco` some of the fields can be visualized. Search `visualize.lco` in the documentation.

Comment: I have never worked with LaTeX documentation files before, and they did not seem too straightforward. I will give it another shot as soon as I find some time.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your preamble to visualize boxes that are normally of interest while designing a letter layout (changing lengths).

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{head,address,location,refline,foot}
```

According to the manual, this are all boxes (+`test` showing a 10 x 15 cm rectangle for print calibration) that can be shown this way. One needs to go a different way to visualize the rest of the gray boxes shown in your figure above.

A complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% change some lengths ------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
% Text block
\areaset{160mm}{237mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\dimexpr 30mm-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\dimexpr 20mm-1in}

% Letter Head
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{30mm}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{17mm}
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}

% Address Window
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{30mm}
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{45mm}
\@setplength{toaddrwidth}{75mm}
\@setplength{toaddrheight}{45mm}
\@setplength{toaddrindent}{0mm}
\makeatother

% visualize border of boxes in blue ----------------------------
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{head,address,location,refline,foot}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{blue}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}

\begin{letter}{Dr. Moritz Busch\\Georgengarten\\30167 Hannover}
\opening{Mein lieber Freund,}
\blindtext
\par
\blindtext
\closing{Bis bald,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of MWE]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should expand this answer with an example that shows the type of output produced.  While it is not exactly what the author ask for it could be a useful step in the right direction and helpful to others.

Comment: You are right the answer was very terse. It was essentially the stuff i was looking for when i landed here.